# How to call a method of same controller inside another method of same controller in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have this method Mapping

```
@PostMapping("**/filtrarprodutospreco")
public void preprocessamentoprodutos(Pageable pageable, FiltroProdutosDto filtro) {
  filtro.setFiltrarPor("1");
  filtro.setItensPorPag("12");      
  filtrarProdutos(pageable, filtro);        
}
```

After processing the data I want to call this other method with these objects (pageable and filter) of parameter for the second method:

```
@PostMapping("**/filtrarprodutos")
public ModelAndView filtrarProdutos(Pageable pageable, FiltroProdutosDto filtro) {
  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("product");

  Categoria categoria = categoriaRepository.findById(filtro.getCategoriaId()).get();

  if(filtro.getPrecoDe() == null) {
      filtro.setPrecoDe(0D);
  }
  if(filtro.getPrecoAte() == null) {
      filtro.setPrecoAte(1000000000D);
  }


  if(filtro.getFiltrarPor().contains("1")){
    model.addObject("produtos", produtoRepository.filtroProdutos(categoria, filtro.getPrecoDe(), filtro.getPrecoAte(), PageRequest.of(0, Integer.parseInt(filtro.getItensPorPag()), Sort.by("nome"))));
  }else {
    model.addObject("produtos", produtoRepository.filtroProdutos(categoria, filtro.getPrecoDe(), filtro.getPrecoAte(), PageRequest.of(0, Integer.parseInt(filtro.getItensPorPag()), Sort.by("precoNovo"))));
    }

  model.addObject("id", filtro.getCategoriaId());
  model.addObject("categorias", categoriaRepository.findAll());
  model.addObject("filtro", filtro);
  return model;
}
```

This second method uses ModelAndView to redirect the pages, so I want to be called by the first method. Spring calls the second method with the objects and the second method takes those objects and returns to the page configured in (ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("product")).
How do I make the first method call the second and redirect to a view?

Comment: Where is the question? In the future make sure there is one sentence with a question mark.

Comment: thks, I edited this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the first method return a String and return a redirect to the second method like so:

```
@PostMapping("**/filtrarprodutospreco")
public String preprocessamentoprodutos(Pageable pageable, FiltroProdutosDto filtro) {
    filtro.setFiltrarPor("1");
    filtro.setItensPorPag("12");      
    filtrarProdutos(pageable, filtro);        
    return "redirect:/filtrarprodutos";
}
```